How to request document diagnostics using Omnisharp?
I try to request diagnostics from my LSP using the following code
var report = await client.RequestDocumentDiagnostic(new DocumentDiagnosticParams()
{
    TextDocument = textDocument,
    Identifier = "luau"
});

Console.WriteLine(report);

Where client is my LanguageClient that I've initialized. Other methods like RequestCompletion and RequestHover work as expected.
However, when I try to call the RequestDocumentDiagnostic method, it gives me the following error:
Unhandled exception. System.NotImplementedException: The method or operation is not implemented.
   at OmniSharp.Extensions.LanguageServer.Protocol.Models.RelatedDocumentDiagnosticReport.Converter.ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, RelatedDocumentDiagnosticReport existingValue, Boolean hasExistingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConverter`1.ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.DeserializeConvertable(JsonConverter converter, JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken.ToObject(Type objectType, JsonSerializer jsonSerializer)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken.ToObject[T](JsonSerializer jsonSerializer)
   at OmniSharp.Extensions.JsonRpc.ResponseRouter.ResponseRouterReturnsImpl.Returning[TResponse](CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at OmniSharp.Extensions.LanguageServer.Protocol.Progress.ProgressManager.<>c__DisplayClass26_0`1.<<MakeRequest>b__0>d.MoveNext()

There is little documentation on the language client package from Omnisharp and I don't know why I'm getting this error.
I tried different methods of getting the diagnostics from the LSP like directly using client.SendRequest but I couldn't get that to work.

Figured it out.
            var report = Client.SendRequest("textDocument/diagnostic", new DocumentDiagnosticParams
        {
            TextDocument = document,
            
        });

        var item = await report.Returning<DiagnosticItem>(CancellationToken.None);

        return item;


Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?
